# Discord.js Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Hi I have a problem with adding a role, I wanted to make a verify command where you get the role verified and get access to channels but when I use the command I get a console error like this "(node:16400) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined" code below

```
 if (message.content === `${prefix}verify`) {
    message.delete();
    if (message.channel.id === '838040640377585664') {
      let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "838037327589670962");

      message.author.roles.add(role);

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`author` refers to a `user`. You want to access the `member` for that `user` given the current `guild`. Or, for short, just access `.member` instead of `.author`.

```js
 message.member.roles.add(role);
```